# Ever been asked to send money to this man?

Tags: international-transfer, international

Has anyone ever been contacted by someone named Richard Atul who claims to be an orthopaedic surgeon working for the UN in Yemen. He's asked me to send money to help him get home because they won't grant him emergency leave. He won't give me specific information I can use to verify his identify like his home address, the organization that issued his MD license, or the exact UN department he works for, so I suspect this is a SCAM.

Any advice would be helpful.  Thank you!

Comment: Just curious. Why are you worried about it? Have you thought about why this person is reaching out to you, out of nowhere, instead of perhaps family and friends?

Comment: UN isn't what it used to be... https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/109749/us-doctor-working-in-tripoli-wants-me-to-open-online-account

Comment: I could pick a wide range of duplicate questions, but I wish SE had a way of generally addressing all those. General. Not specific, because the scammers come up with new excuses, scenarios, situations.

Answer (score 7):

It's a scam.

Why else would a stranger contact you and ask you for money?